# How to set 50 Hz sampling rate of accelerometer and gyroscope on android?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sampling, gyroscope

I want to store the data collected by the accelerometer and gyroscope of an Android phone. Specifically, I want to sample them on 50 Hz, No more, No less.

How can I specify this on Android Java?

I've seen other post where they use:

```
 mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

Which takes as the maximum amount of samples the sensors can. Though Sometimes the capacity of sensors can reach above 50hz, How can I only take 50 hz?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)), you can specify "the desired delay between events in microseconds", so it should be:

```
 mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, 20000); // 20000 = 50Hz in microseconds
```

*edit: according to the documention:*

> The rate sensor events are delivered at. This is only a hint to the system. Events may be received faster or slower than the specified rate. Usually events are received faster. The value must be one of SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SENSOR_DELAY_UI, SENSOR_DELAY_GAME, or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST or, the desired delay between events in microseconds.

There appears to be no way to be precise, at least with this API.

Comment: but will this delay be proportional to the sampling capability of each sensor device?

Comment: I mean, I will run the app on a generic device, It's sampling capability could be 50 Hz also which means if set the delay to 20000, The sampling rate would be 25Hz?

Comment: @RabbitBadger it is the desired delay between events, so it should be an absolute value, but as the documentation states, it is "only a hint".